# window.open() method with IE 8 - Force window to open outside of tabs

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, tabs, window.open

I am trying to make a program that is opened by physically clickng on the .HTML file, not through a web-page, and I need it to open up in its own window, NOT the same window in a new tab, without giving warnings.

I can not just change the settings in internet explorer on everyones computer.

So far the ONLY thing I have come up with that will make the window open up without a new tab is to have a secondare html file that uses window.open() to open the main file with the correct parameters.

if I do:

```
window.open('mainFile.html','_self','width=540, height=880')
```

it still opens it up in the same window with a new tab, and doesn't resize it.
if I do:

```
window.open('mainFile.html','','width=540, height=880')
window.close('secondFile.html')
```

It opens the main one up in a new window, but prompts the user to close the first file. I don't want anyone to know that the second file is not the main file. This ONLY needs to work in IE-8 with default settings.
*For clarification, the window.open() javascript method is called immediately and automatically upon opening the secondary file, so it can open the main file right away. If someone can think of a clever way to acheive the same results without any extra work on the program users parts, I am open to suggestions.
*I know this has to be possible in some way, as another programmer here made a program in the past with javascript, opened the same way my file is, and it does exactly what this one needs to. but unfortunately, they are not available for questioning and the source code is hidden and not accessable.

Comment: try: <a href='myFile.pdf' target='_blank'>my PDF File</a>

Comment: @jeff He said he's NOT doing this by clicking in a web page, he's clicking on the file in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @Barmar, oops missed that point :-)

Comment: Yes, barmar is correct. It is not a web page or link of any form, but I have also tried the window.open('mainFile.html', '_blank'), and it still just leaves a blank window behind stuck in a new tab in the same window, while opening up the new window in its own tab properly. I need there to not be a blank window left behind.

Answer (score 1):

I GOT IT! Took a ridiculous amount of experimenting, but it works flawlessly now. I feel bad for asking this question now, as it was an extremely simple solution, but for anyone interested, I used a second helper .html file with the lines as follows

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
window.open('','_self',''); // this makes the window re-open itself via javascript
window.open('directory/myRealFile','_blank',','width=540,height=880,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
window.close(); // since javascript opened it, it will close without a prompt
</script>
```